# Assigning a method name to UnityAction(Delegate)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a sample code to declare UnityAction array.
And assign each method on the elements.

```
public class Car {
    int _wheels;
    public Car(int wheels){_wheels = wheels;}
    public void Go(){
        Debug.Log ("GO:"+_wheels);
    }
}

public class UnityEventTest : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start()
    {
        UnityAction []action = new UnityAction[2];

        //case #1
        action[0] = new UnityAction(FuncA);
        //case #2
        action[1] = FuncB;

        action[0].Invoke ();
        action[1].Invoke ();

        //----------------------------------
        Car aCar = new Car(1);
        Car bCar = new Car(2);

        Car []carList = new Car[2];
        carList[0] = aCar;
        carList[1] = bCar;

        carList[0].Go();
        carList[1].Go();
    }
    void FuncA(){Debug.Log ("A");}
    void FuncB(){Debug.Log ("B");}
}
```

Both of *Case #1* and *Case #2* work well.

Output:

```
A
B
GO:1
GO:2
```

But, I don't understand why *case #2* works? 
There may be no UnityAction instance in each array elements. 
The code just assign class's method. And, As far as I know **C# delegate**(like **UnityAction**) is a **reference data type**.

So I think *case #2* should make some error or can not be assigned.

Unlike the car's case below, I think a method name is not an instance.

Comment: where is unityAction?

Comment: UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction

Comment: What do you mean by "There may be no UnityAction instance in each array elements."? What should cause a null pointer error there?

Comment: ah~ right. I just edit and elaborate my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first thing is notice that `UnityAction()` is a void delegate. 
If you look the Declaration you can confirm that:

```
//From Assembly sourcecode:
namespace UnityEngine.Events
{
    public delegate void UnityAction ();
}
```

So in Case#1 you are creating a void delegate from `FuncA`, since `FuncA` returns void there are no problem doing that (you can try to change `void FuncA` to `int FuncA` and see what happens :) )!

Now in Case#2 you are directly assigning `FuncB` (which is a method) to a UnityAction(delegate) without using any kind of explicit or implicit cast!

So how this can work? Well, the answer seem to be a thing called **[delegate-method-group-conversion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ff5320f-8037-4064-870c-394f7cad9d03/c-20-delegate-method-group-conversion?forum=csharplanguage)** that :

> "...simplifies the syntax used to assign a method to a delegate. Method
>   group conversion allows you to assign the name of a method to a
>   delegate, without the use new or explicitly invoking the delegate's
>   constructor."

So, without any special syntax you can assign a method to a delegate, in this particular case, a UnityAction.